# Rails skipping ID, possible database MySQL transactions issues?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, transactions

I have two application servers running Ruby on Rails sharing the same MySQL database server, using InnoDB engine.

Sometimes under heavy load I find that IDs from the records are skipped in the table Users, X and Y and are not sequential.

This is the pseudo code:

```
user = Create user x in table Users

user_x = Find user x

Insert a tuple into an auxiliary table X

Insert a tuple into an auxiliary table Y

Update the tuple that was inserted in table X

Insert a tuple into an auxiliary table Z
```

Tables X, Y, Z, are all related in someway, and I am not deleting any records.

However, I find that sometimes record IDs will skip one or two during heavy load.

Would transaction help with this case?

```
Start transaction

  user = Create user x

  user_x = Find user x

  Insert a tuple into an auxiliary table X

  Insert a tuple into an auxiliary table Y

  Update the tuple that was inserted in table X

  Insert a tuple into an auxiliary table Z

Commit
```

Noobie question, this code works fine when there is no load, but once if there is a load. ie multiple users hitting the same resource at the exact same time, then the above happens. Would a transaction help?

What disadvantages would there be to wrap everything in transaction blocks?

Comment: Adding transactions will have little effect on the skipping of auto-increment values. However, if you need the records you're inserting into Users, X, Y, and Z to either all exist or all fail, you would want a transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about MYSQL, but in Postgres ids are only allocated once from the autoincrementing sequence and will be unused if a transaction is rolled back or aborted.

You're best off looking at why it is a problem that some ids are skipped. Anything relying on them to be sequential is suspect.

Are you using Foreign Keys between Users and tables X, Y, and Z? Or does the relationship depend on the ids incrementing in parallel?

Comment: The ID does not need to be sequential for the application. I suppose I just want to see why it is skipping since I am not deleting rows or updating IDs.

No I am not using foreign keys, the Rails application does not use foreign keys in their database schema migration.

Comment: @Bill To make sequence incrementing low-overhead and non-blocking, most database engines will allocate chunks of values to connections. In the case of an error, disconnect, or server reboot, they are skipped and the auto incremented value is not rolled back.

Comment: Much thanks, the comment in the question answered my question. Also, I suppose it would be common to see skipped IDs in an environment where the application server is replicated.

Comment: @Bill Yes, the more connections you have inserting, the more you'll see skipped. Also, I believe that any manual inserts that supply the id field, rather than pulling from the auto-incrementing value, will reset the auto-increment to be MAX(id) + 1.